# Is it reasonable to model row buffers in DRAM corresponding to the same bank ID as one big row buffer?

Tags: computer-architecture, memory-management, simulation, memory-hardware

I'm creating a simple row buffer simulator to go along with a simple cache simulator in order to count hits and misses in the row buffer. Whenever a cache block isn't in the cache I want to go look for it in the row buffers of the main memory and record whether it is present of not.

How accurate would it be to have just one long "row buffer" struct containing all the data found in all the individual row buffers of each corresponding bank in each DRAM chip? Say that each chip has 8 banks, I would then have to create 8 of these extra long row buffers to simulate these chips. This idea is based on the understanding that all these chips work in unison, so that if I want to load the cache block at address 0, the row buffers of bank 0 in each chip would fill with data from addresses starting at address 0 in chip 0, and ending at address 0 + (length of row buffer * number of DRAM chips) in the last chip. It would assume a row interleaved address mapping (with consecutive rows in consecutive banks) for simplicity's sake.

Are there any major misunderstandings about how DRAM works that causes this to be a very bad way to model row buffer behavior or is this a reasonable simplification? I'd also like to underscore that simplicity is the main goal here.

EDIT *added clarification on question posted in comments below*:
I assume that all the row buffers for banks with ID, say, 0 work together in unison on the same read or write, with all of them containing data for that particular operation. Couldn't I model these 8 row buffers (if I have 8 DRAM chips) as just one very big row buffer? The total size of this combined row buffer would be the length of the normal row buffer*number of DRAM chips. So if I were to a model chips with 8 banks for example, I'd have 8 of these "combined" row buffers, one for each bank.

Comment: Having a single row buffer is like saying there is a single bank only. If you just want to demonstrate the performance impact of row buffer misses using a really simple example, then I guess this would be OK. This might even be realistic for very low-end processors (tiny and very low-power).

Comment: Thanks for the reply! Maybe I wasn't to clear in what my proposed model was. I assume that all the row buffers for banks with ID, say, 0 work together in unison on the same read or write, with all of them containing data for that particular operation.  Couldn't I model these 8 row buffers (if I have 8 DRAM chips) as just one very big row buffer? The total size of this combined row buffer would be the length of the normal row buffer*number of DRAM chips. So if I were to a model chips with 8 banks for example, I'd have 8 of these "combined" row buffers, one for each bank.

Comment: Oh  I think I misunderstood. Yeah that's how it typically works actually. But it also does depend on the protocol (e.g., DDR3) and the memory controller policy. If the protocol supports a granularity of access smaller than the width of the bus (i.e., 8 bytes), then the memory controller may open only the rows from the required chips and not the other chips. I think something like this is rare in reality and usually the rows of the same bank from all chips are managed together as a single unit.

Comment: Oh, okay. Thanks! This is the answer I was looking for! You can post it as a reply, and I'll mark the question as answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can look at how one of the existing DRAM simulators work. Consider, for example, [Ramulator](https://github.com/CMU-SAFARI/ramulator), which is a popular academic DRAM simulator. Ramulator Models main memory as a tree of nodes, where the root node represents a memory channel and lower nodes represent ranks, bank groups (supported in DDR4), banks, rows, and columns. For the DRR4 and DRR3 protocols, these levels are defined in the source code [here](https://github.com/CMU-SAFARI/ramulator/blob/845ca6a79f2d776265514bfebe8febc60448232b/src/DDR4.h#L26) and [here](https://github.com/CMU-SAFARI/ramulator/blob/845ca6a79f2d776265514bfebe8febc60448232b/src/DDR3.h#L28), respectively. Therefore, the physical row buffer of each chip of the same bank are actually treated as a single row buffer whose state is maintained using a single value.

Comment: Thanks a lot! This is great!